# Why does the value assigned to it by getElementById become a constant after the variable name is set to name?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, getelementbyid

My HTMl's source code is as follows：

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>查找内部HTML并修改对应元素的内容</title>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="zxj">hello</p>
        <script src="innerhtml.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

My javascript's resource code as follows:

```
var name = document.getElementById("zxj");
name.innerHTML = "test";
console.log(name.innerHTML)
```

When I run the above code, I get undefined from the console.So I checked my variable ***name*** and found the problem。The variable named ***name*** is a `const name:never`.I found that the ***name*** variable I declared is a constant. That's why I get an undefined when I access its innerHTML property.
When I changed the variable ***name*** to ***names***, the console output the correct result.

```
var names = document.getElementById("zxj");
names.innerHTML = "test";
console.log(names.innerHTML)
```

At this time, the variable of ***names*** becomes an element object, so I can modify its corresponding innerHTML value.

Why can't the variable name be set to ***name***? Why does the value assigned to it by getElementById become a constant after the variable name is set to ***name***? Can anyone tell me why?
I am very confused! ! !

Comment: Probably due to the collision with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name

Comment: You can't use `name` as the name of a global variable on browsers. It conflicts with the built-in `name` which is a property of the `window` object (and thus a global). This is one of the many good reasons not to use global variables at all. Instead, use modules (`script type="module"`), using a bundler if you have to support older environments that don't support them.